# How to call method from UItableview delegate

Tags: iphone, ios6

1)  My problem: how to call NumberofRowsInSection  of UItableViewDataSource Method of another UItableViewdataSource.

2 ) HOw to make aggrateTableViewDataSource from n number of Different CustomTableViewDataSource?

Need Help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some conceptional confusion in your question.

`datasource` is a **delegate protocol**. That means that you can have a **class** that adopts that protocol. That again means that it has certain required or optional methods, e.g. `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` in the case of the protocol `UITableViewDataSource`.

Therefore there is no such thing as "two datasources". If your class that implements the datasource protocol has more than one source for its data, that's a different kind of "data source" - and a question completely unrelated to the `datasource` protocol for table views.

Of course, you can have **more than one** `UITableView` that refers to the **same** class as its `datasource`. This is actually common for search tables which typically can display both the original and the search result table. In this case, you check in your datasource methods which table view is requesting the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make a model that calculates this from the source, not the tables. If you are using core data, create a class that fetches the objects and calculates the figures then observes changes to update the basis for the figures. Make your aggregate functions output as read only properties.
If not core data use, I'd need more info to advise.